# How to parse xml using DOM

Tags: xml-parsing

**Hi All**
I have a xml file like

```
<Amt><InstdAmt Ccy="ABCD">1200.00</InstdAmt><EqvtAmt><Amt/><CcyOfTrf/></EqvtAmt></Amt>
```

how will read value of **Ccy** that is ABCD

I am writing program in java and using DOM as a parser.
I can only use DOM or SAX parser

**THANKS A LOT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here, you just need to read the attribut value

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code, where fileInputStream is xml file you previously loaded as stream:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
....
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = db.parse(fileInputStream);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("InstdAmt");
        int len = nodeList.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element e = (Element)node;

                String attrVal = e.getAttribute("Ccy"); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: **Thanks All** it is sloved it can be get by attribute